# Change component state from another component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to do the same sidebar in NextJS [original sidebar](https://codepen.io/chris__sev/pen/RwKWXpJ). For that I created two components:

component for menu button:

```
export default function MobileMenuBtn() {

return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800 text-gray-100 flex justify-between md:hidden">
        <div className="block p-4 text-white font-bold">Better Dev</div>
        <button onClick={()=>???????????} className="mobile-menu-button p-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700">
        <svg className="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
        </svg>
        </button>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

and component for sidebar itself:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
return (
    <div className="sidebar bg-blue-800 text-blue-100 w-64 space-y-6 py-7 px-2 absolute inset-y-0 left-0 
    transform -translate-x-full md:relative md:translate-x-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out">
        <div className="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            Verb To Be
        </div>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

To show/hide sidebar when I click menu button I was trying to use useState but the problem is I don't know how to change the state of **Sidebar** component from **MobileMenuBtn**.

Comment: Can you please provide us the problem example in codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sidebar component + MobileMenuBtn need to have access to read / write to a common state.

The simplest solution:
In their parent component (the component that is rendering `<Sidebar />` and `<MobileMenuBtn />`) you can create a common state and pass the related information to each of the components:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false);

const handleChangeSidebar = () => setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);

return (
  <>
   <Sidebar open={showSidebar} />
   <MobileMenuBtn onClick={handleChangeSidebar} />
  </>
);
}
```

With this, both of your components receive the necessary information:

Sidebar:

```
export default function Sidebar({ open }) {
// now you can conditionally render on open === true and open === false
return (
    <div className="sidebar bg-blue-800 text-blue-100 w-64 space-y-6 py-7 px-2 absolute inset-y-0 left-0 
    transform -translate-x-full md:relative md:translate-x-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out">
        <div className="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            Verb To Be
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

MobileMenuBtn

```
export default function MobileMenuBtn({ onClick }) {

return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800 text-gray-100 flex justify-between md:hidden">
        <div className="block p-4 text-white font-bold">Better Dev</div>
        <button onClick={onClick} className="mobile-menu-button p-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700">
        <svg className="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
        </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
);
}
```

Another approach would be: [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)